# Pygame gives me TypeError: add() argument after * must be a sequence, not Ball when adding Ball to sprite group

Tags: oop, python-2.7, pygame, sprite

Recently, I have been messing around with `pygame` and I decided to make a pong clone.  However, I am running into problems with the `ball` class.

This is my class:

```
    class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        """ This class represents the ball that bounces around. """

        # Constructor function
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            # Call the parent's constructor
            pygame.sprite.Sprite().__init__(self)

            # Set height, width
            self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
            self.image.fill(white)

            # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.y = y
            self.rect.x = x

            # Set speed vector
            self.change_x = 0
            self.change_y = 0

        def goal(self):
            if self.rect.x <= SCREEN_WIDTH:
                playerscore =+ 1
                print playerscore
            elif self.rect.x >= 0:
                aiscore =+ 1
                print aiscore

        def update(self):
            """ Update the ball's position. """
            # Get the old position, in case we need to go back to it
            old_x = self.rect.x
            new_x = old_x + self.change_x
            self.rect.x = new_x

            # Did this update cause us to hit a wall?
            collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, allsprites_list, False)
            if collide:
                # Whoops, hit a wall. Go back to the old position
                self.rect.x = old_x
                self.change_x *= -1

            old_y = self.rect.y
            new_y = old_y + self.change_y
            self.rect.y = new_y

            # Did this update cause us to hit a wall?
            collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, allsprites_list, False)
            if collide:
                # Whoops, hit a wall. Go back to the old position
                self.rect.y = old_y
                self.change_y *= -1

            if self.rect.x < -20 or self.rect.x > screen_width + 20:
                self.change_x = 0
                self.change_y = 0
```

This adds the ball to a sprite group:

```
    self.ball = Ball(100, 250)
    self.all_sprites_list.add(self.ball)
```

And this is the traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Enigma/Desktop/pong.py", line 312, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:/Users/Enigma/Desktop/pong.py", line 290, in main
        game = Game()
      File "C:/Users/Enigma/Desktop/pong.py", line 218, in __init__
        self.ball = Ball(100, 250)
      File "C:/Users/Enigma/Desktop/pong.py", line 83, in __init__
        pygame.sprite.Sprite().__init__(self)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 114, in __init__
        if groups: self.add(groups)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 129, in add
        else: self.add(*group)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 129, in add
        else: self.add(*group)
    TypeError: add() argument after * must be a sequence, not Ball
```

I have searched the web and all of the posts that I could find here at SO, however none of the seem to apply to this particular conundrum. Any and all help would be appreciated.

I am running python 2.7.9 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
pygame.sprite.Sprite().__init__(self)
```

is almost certainly wrong. You want to call the method on the class, not an instance.

```
pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
```

Comment: Thank you. That problem s solved. However the ball appears but does not move. How would I fix this (I have added the new code in an edit)?

Comment: Not sure. But if you want to ask a new question you should open a new question.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to update it. I am removing the update.